# 2 installations of chrome displaying Absolute positioning differently

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome on my PC is rendering our webpage just fine.  On my Boss' Chrome browser, the absolute positioning of a drop down menu item is higher than it is supposed to be.  Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?  I have checked multiple other installations of Chrome and they are all rendering correctly.  Just my Boss' machine is incorrect.  Please Help!

here are some screenshots...

http://www.securityselling.com/img/Good-Menu-Screenshot.jpg

http://www.securityselling.com/img/Bad-Menu-Screenshot.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Can it be the Screen Resolution? Or maybe some add0n from your bosse's Chrome?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I asked him to hide any extra toolbars that he has installed on his Chrome browser.  I will certainly post the results of that here if this changes anything.

Comment: I don't think it is a resolution issue as I have changed mine to every setting possible and everything still renders fine.

Comment: Should also mention that we confirmed that we are both using the same version of Chrome (21.0.1180.83 m) and that they are both up to date.